# Adding Multiple Criteria Using FILTER Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a sheet to where I update a tab and it automatically populates another tab sorting only the data I want to see. I used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1587989/multiple-criteria-with-if-isnumber-search) article originally for help, and it seemed to work for 1 row of criteria. However - if I add a second row of criteria, and try to select more than 1 range, the function doesn't seem to work.

[Picture of Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILA5q.jpg)

Working code:

```
=FILTER(PTP,
(ISNUMBER(FIND($X$2,PTP[Status])))*  
(PTP[Ping Active]=$Y$2)*
(PTP[Facility Type]=$Z$2)*
(PTP[Ping Resolution Status]=$AA$2))
```

Code that doesn't work I'm looking for an alternative to:

```
=FILTER(PTP,
(ISNUMBER(FIND($X$2,PTP[Status])))*
(PTP[Ping Active]=$Y$2:$Y$3)*
(PTP[Facility Type]=$Z$2:$Z$3)*
(PTP[Ping Resolution Status]=$AA$2:$AA$3))
```

Also in the picture I provided, for that column I'm looking for the criteria for that specific column to allow a blank cell in said criteria (denoted by *blank*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ISNUMBER(MATCH())

```
=FILTER(PTP,
(ISNUMBER(FIND($X$2,PTP[Status])))*
(ISNUMBER(MATCH(PTP[Ping Active],$Y$2:$Y$3,0)))*
(ISNUMBER(MATCH(PTP[Facility Type],$Z$2:$Z$3,0)))*
(ISNUMBER(MATCH(PTP[Ping Resolution Status],$AA$2:$AA$3,0))))
```

Filter already is iterating and trying to do the second level makes it throw an error.

By using MATCH we can see if it exists in the array and only iterate the one level.

Comment: Awesome! That was simple. I'm new to excel and slowly learning, I appreciate it! Is there a way to add a filter for a blank column? Some criteria is either "open" or blank, I would like to accept both of them in the filter. Thank you!!

Comment: @JohnStalls that gets more difficult because match does not like blanks in the first criterion.  This would need to be totally reworked. with some `IF` statements to make them not blank.   Something like `ISNUMBER(MATCH(IF(PTP[Ping Active]<>"",TP[Ping Active],"zzzz"),IF($Y$2:$Y$3<>"",$Y$2:$Y$3,"zzzz"),0))` should work

Comment: Works like a charm!